# Collision Domains: Switch connected with two hubs

Tags: networking, domain, switch, hub

I know there are already some topics concerning Collision Domains, but I think my question is still specific enough to warrant a specific answer.

- I understand collisions only occur on half-duplex connections. I
  understand a switch/bridge is capable of full-duplex communication,
  where a hub/repeater is only capable of half-duplex communication.
- I understand that the duplex mode of a link is determined by the
  "weakest station" in this link (i.e. if a hub and a switch connect
  directly, the link will be half-duplex).
- I know that a switch/bridge is said to cut up collision domains, but
  I do not understand it completely.

Given below image:

https://www.lucidchart.com/documents/view/4c2d7dd0-7411-4d9f-b576-920628cd8ae7

Since both hubs are only capable of half-duplex communication, the bridge will connect to both of them with a half-duplex link. At this point, I don't see how it matters if this bridge is a bridge or a repeater, as it has to work half-duplex anyway.

Thus, my question is: how exactly does the bridge prevent packages from the one computer colliding with the other, and if it does not, why are both computers not considered to be in the same collision domain? Since a collision domain is supposed to be a domain in which packages from stations can collide with each other (which they can everywhere here in my mind).